# Unable to use usercontrols in my project

Tags: wpf, user-controls, reference

I'm working on a WPF solution. For some odd reasons, I'm getting the error "The type '...' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference..." every time I add a usercontrol/custom control through XAML. I did build the solution, had the namespace declaration for XAML, made sure I had the correct assembly name, and made sure that the usercontrol itself doesn't contain any errors.

What's even weirder is that, when I ignore the errors and add the controls manually through the XAML editor (heck, even InteliSense in the XAML editor works), then build & run it, **everything works** (I'm guessing this means that there's no problem with the solution itself)

The controls show up in the toolbox, but I can't add it through the designer. As I stated, adding through the XAML editor/in code behind works, but it's really inconvenient. Adding through the XAML editor also raises the error, and stops the designer from loading, so it's even more annoying. Adding through code behind is just inelegant, and makes it hard for debugging.

EDIT: Opening the solution on a different computer doesn't solve the problem, so it's not a problem caused by Visual Studio. Also tested moving everything to a new project, still doesn't work, which means it's not a problem with the configurations, likely a problem with the code. If then, how come it builds & runs, and even IntelliSense works and the designer doesn't?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using that causes this error? Mainly your namespace definition and the usercontrol tag

Comment: The designer gives a lot of errors like this that aren't real errors. Are you just seeing an error in the designer, or does it also (a) fail to compile or (b) compile, but throw an exception at runtime?

Comment: Well, the full code is rather long, but as I stated, it works fine when I build & run it, so it's not a problem with the code.
Indeed, this is a situation when the designer gives an error message for no real reason (even InteliSense in the XAML designer works, so it's not a problem with my namespace definition). I only see the error in the designer. But VS works normally with other projects & the problem's still there after I restart VS (haven't tried reinstalling it/opening the solution on another computer though...really hope I won't have to)

Comment: This is not an answer, but an observation that may be of help in getting to the answer.  A big difference between dropping a control into the designer and adding it manually is that in the process of dropping, VS does some coercion on its dependency properties whereas entering the Xaml manually does not cause coercion.  So you might want to look into the internals of the user control.  Hope that helps...

Comment: The designer doesn't even allow me to drop (after I select it from the toolbox, the design view is disabled, and the cursor doesn't change), and all the user controls fail to work with the designer, with one only consists of a simple checkbox & textbox, with properties related to them (no dependency properties). I also tried various things, like using working controls from other projects, or a brand new, blank user control. Nothing works.
Also, entering the XAML manually does raise the same errors, as I stated, it prevents the designer from loading.

Comment: Can you post up the exact error message you get? Also, it might be worth creating a small test project just to try to replicate and isolate your issue. I think I may have had the same issue as you before though.

Comment: Well I think this error message is pretty common, but has various causes. I find myself unable to replicate the error (created a new project, using the very same user controls & namespace definition albeit with a different project name, everything worked). When I just moved everything from this project to a blank one, however, that code doesn't work. So, basically, it's not because of the code , the config, nor my VS installation (or perhaps it's because of the code...somewhere else...like where?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay...nevermind, it's because I built it for x64, and apparently the designer just doesn't work with that since it's x86. Using "AnyCPU" seems to work.